# What does NHibernate.AssertionFailure on doing transaction.Commit() mean?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

`I am a newbie to programming Windows forms application. I am stuck with an error for the past 2 days. I had a method`Add()` in the Base DAO layer

```
public virtual void Add(T entity)
{
    try
    {
        DomainObject domObj = entity as DomainObject;
        if (domObj != null)
        {
            domObj.CreatedDate = domObj.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        }

        using (ITransaction transaction = GetTransaction)
        {
            _session.Save(entity);
            //******* _session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
            // _session.Refresh(entity);
            //transaction.Commit();

        }
    }
```

I tried to move the `transaction.Commit()` into a separate method in the Base DAO layer.

```
public virtual void Commit(T entity)
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = GetTransaction)
    {
        transaction.Commit();
    } 
}
```

I have made corresponding changes in the rest of the layers. Now when I run the application and enter data into the form I am getting this exception(NHibernate.AssertionFailure). Please help.

This is MarketScenario entity class code :

```
namespace RKG.SCM.ModelObjects
```

{
    public class MarketScenarioModel
    {
        public MarketScenarioModel() { }

```
    public MarketScenarioModel(string selectedMarketIds) 
    {
        this.MarketIdList = selectedMarketIds;
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ScenarioModel ScenarioModel { get; set; }
    public virtual string MarketIdList { get; set; }
}
```

}
 And this is the MarketScenario NHibernate mapping:

namespace RKG.SCM.NHibernate.Mappings {

```
public class MarketScenarioMap : ClassMap<MarketScenario> {

    public MarketScenarioMap() {
        Table("market_scenario");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("id");
        References(x => x.Scenario).Column("scenario_id");
        Map(x => x.MarketIdList).Column("market_id_list");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: AssertionFailure was unhandled null id in RKG.SCM.DomainObjects.MarketScenario entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could show your MarketScenario entity class code and its mapping (xhbm or fluent or whatever you use).

It looks like its primary key is not identity (auto generated) and you try to save an object with null Id. If it was an identity column, than it would be ok.

Of course, it depends on what identity generation strategy you'd like to use. I think that you should tell us a bit more about this entity and its identity column.

Comment: The MarketScenario entity class code and its mapping has been added in the edited question.

Comment: It seems to be a bit strange. Maybe the primary key is not a problem. Could you investigate your exception a bit? There are often useful properties and stack traces in .NET exceptions. Try to post a picture or text dump of your exception so it will be possible to investigate your problem.